# Elasticsearch query dates while using the querystring

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to to query in the dats while using the querystring.

From what I can read [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html)  this should work.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "date:[20100101 TO 20141231]"

        }
    },
    "size": 10

}
```

I get no errors but no results either.

I have date fields in the mapping (shortened for your convenience).

```
{
   "cases": {
      "mappings": {
         "texcaseelastic": {
            "properties": {
               "dateIn": {
                  "type": "date",
                  "format": "dateOptionalTime"
               },
               "type": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And I have at least a few that should fall in that range.

```
"dateIn": "2011-11-21T00:00:00",
```

Any help would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Is that a typo in your query, that your field name is `date` instead of `dateIn`?

Comment: No, that is how I understand it to work, I thought date meant all fields with a date in them. But you are saying that that should be my fieldname datin?

Comment: Yes. Should be field name.

Comment: darn, stupid me. Can you make that an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: can I do a search on all date fields for a date with the querystring

Comment: I think leveraging the _all field will be your best option. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html You can use a mapping dynamic template to ensure all date fields are in included in the _all field. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html#_dynamic_templates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a typo in your query. You are doing a search by specific field and your field name is incorrect.

Change `date` to `dateIn`, like the following:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "dateIn:[20100101 TO 20141231]"

        }
    },
    "size": 10

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "query":{"range": {"date_column_name": {"gte": "2011-11-20T00:00:00", "lte": "2011-11-22T00:00:00"}}},
    "size": 10
}
```